# Testing whether list elements are strings in CL

Tags: string, list, lisp, common-lisp

I'm trying to learn Common Lisp (sbcl) and getting practice with basic defuns. I'm trying to write one now that adds the lengths of all the strings in a list.

An early step is testing whether the first element is a string. I assumed you could call this with

`(stringp (car '(s1 s2)))`

where s1 and s2 are strings. Testing s1 with stringp, and asking for the car of the list seem to work ok, but combining them together doesn't give me what I expect:

```
CL-USER> (car '(s1 s2))
S1
CL-USER> (stringp s1)
T
CL-USER> (stringp (car '(s1 s2)))
NIL
```

Am I misunderstanding the stringp function, or the way lists work?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`'(s1 s2)` is a list containing the symbols `s1` and `s2`. So `(car '(s1 s2))` returns the symbol `s1` (as you can see by the fact that the REPL prints `S1` and not whatever string is stored in the variable `s1`. Since a symbol is not a string, `stringp` returns false.

If you actually use a list of strings, it will work as you expect:

```
* (car (list s1 s2))
"contents of s1"

* (stringp (car (list s1 s2)))
T
```

Answer (score 2):

The QUOTE prevents the evaluation of its enclosed form. The enclosed form is returned as is.

`(car '(s1 s2))` returns `S1`. Which is a symbol and not a string.

If you evaluate `s1`, then Lisp returns its value. But that uses another evaluation step.

If you look at `s1` as a symbol, then it stays a symbol if you tell Lisp:

```
CL-USER > 's1
S1

CL-USER > (stringp 's1)
NIL
```